Отправка сообщений с сайта на почту php
Пишу небольшой сайт и на нем необходимо реализовать подтверждение кодом аккаунта при регистрации. Было решено делать это через почту. Код генерируется записывается в текстовый файл(openserver в папке email), но при загрузке на хостинги не происходит ничего, сообщения не отправляются. Искала решения в различных статьях и видео. Закидывала их исходники также на хостинги, чтобы проверить и снова мимо, не работает ничего, либо пишет, что запрос не может быть обработан. Последнее написанное решение приведено ниже.
$name = $first_name;
$email = $email;
$text = 'Код для регистрации: '.$kod;
$to = 'ххх@mail.ru';
$from = $email;
$subject = 'Код для регистрации';
$msg = "$text";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $from ");

В видео все работает, у меня же не работает ничего. В чем может быть проблема? Буду рада любому ответу.

На хостинге может быть отключена функция mail().

В 2024-м году уже никто не пользуется функцией mail.

@u_mulder в 2024г у меня для тебя плохие новости. Не пользуются mail разве что отмороженные гики и те, кто не могут с ним справиться и не понимают о сливе данных своих клиентов.

В первую очередь во from должен быть домен сайта с которого идёт отправка. А вообще всё есть в логах.

@SeVlad В первую очередь надо читать вопрос. И рассказать нам, что такое "домен сайта" в песочнице openserver под виндоуз. Какие у него  NS, DKIM, SPF.

@Ипатьев согласен надо читать вопрос, чтобы понять - речь о проблеме на хостинге, а не в виндозном недосервере. И не выдумывать про вложения, регулярно мешая юзерам получать ответы.

при проблемах на хостинге надо очевидно обращаться в службу поддержки хостинга, а не писать в Спортлото на деревню дедушке.
